# Query builder problem

Tags: mysql

I've a problem creating and executing a query, when i made in the phpMyAdmin this execute with success but when I execute with postman, this show me an error, I'm using laravel with query builder to make the query

```
$report = DB::table('directoscount')->select('parte', DB::raw('SUM(cantidad)'))->whereNull('deleted_at')->groupBy('parte');

    

$report = DB::table(DB::raw("({$report->toSQL()}) as conteoDirectos"))->leftJoin(
        DB::raw('(SELECT material, bUn, SUM(totalStock), type, storageBin FROM `lx02` WHERE deleted_at IS null GROUP BY material ) as lx02'),
        function($join){
            $join->on('conteoDirectos.parte', '=', 'lx02.material');
        }
    )->get();
```

this is the problem that postman show me

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'ifa.lx02.bUn' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from (select `parte`, SUM(cantidad) from `directoscount` where `deleted_at` is null group by `parte`) as conteoDirectos left join (SELECT material, bUn, SUM(totalStock), type, storageBin FROM `lx02` WHERE deleted_at IS null GROUP BY material ) as lx02 on `conteoDirectos`.`parte` = `lx02`.`material`)",
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! We are SQL people - **some** of us may have used PHP in the past - please run your SQL from the `mysql` CLI tool. If it doesn't work there - then it's a problem for us. If you're having a PHP problem, then it's  a question for StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
    from  
    (
        SELECT  `parte`, SUM(cantidad)
            from  `directoscount`
            where  `deleted_at` is null
            group by  `parte`
    ) as conteoDirectos
    left join  
    (
        SELECT  material,
                bUn,               -- Remove; unused and causes error
                SUM(totalStock),
                type,              -- Remove; unused and causes error
                storageBin
            FROM  `lx02`
            WHERE  deleted_at IS null
            GROUP BY  material 
    ) as lx02  ON `conteoDirectos`.`parte` = `lx02`.`material`
```

Do you need `bUn` and `type` in the outer `SELECT *`?  If so, *which* `bUn` and `type` do you want?  They don't seem to be uniquely identified by `material`.

Comment: yes, I need those fields the ones that is not so important is storageBin but in laravel I cant make the query works i don't know why

Comment: Yet again, a package that is intends to help with queries simply gets in the way?